# Deleting AWS volume when Instance is already deleted?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've started a paying instance on aws platform. I couldn't get my docker to work and I deleted the instance again.

I see I still have a volume attached. And I can't delete it?

Quick read says I need to remove it from terminal connection in my instance. But that's no option anymore. I'm asking here before I'm bankrupt.. :)

Comment: Check in EC2 console Volumes.

Comment: A volume cannot be "Attached" if the EC2 instance has been deleted. If the state of the volume is still Attached, then it is probably connect to another instance (that is not terminated/deleted).